# Why copy function is not working inside setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Chrome complains when I try to `copy` inside `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function () { copy('a') }, 0)

Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:26
```

It doesn't work with the `window` scope as well.

```
setTimeout(function () { window.copy('a') }, 0)

Uncaught TypeError: window.copy is not a function
```

Interestingly, if I keep the reference to `copy` and reuse it, it works

```
cc = copy;
setTimeout(function () { cc('a') }, 0);
```

In Firefox, it doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't work even with the saved reference.

Why `copy` function doesn't work inside `setTimeout`, is it a bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432072/x-function-is-not-defined-inside-a-chrome-extension-content-script/18434955 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934462/why-getting-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-error-on-chrome-dev-cons/48935107

Comment: Fun game: Add a Watch for `window.copy`. It's `undefined`. Now type `debugger` into the console and Watch it show up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`copy` is part of the developer tools' [Command Line API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#copyobject) and is not available outside the browser console. For example, trying to execute the command in a JavaScript file that's part of a normal web page you'd get the same error.

When you invoke the command inside the `setTimeout` callback, the execution context is no longer the console so `copy` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: If you like to copy DOM input element value to clipboard then you can execute copy command using this javascript code document.exeCommand("Copy") after selecting input element as mentioned in this sample code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: But then why `console.log` is working inside `setTimeout`?

Comment: `console` is not exclusively a console command. It's available everywhere, `copy` is not.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by the mention of `with` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935107/4200446), I discovered that you can use it to make `copy()` available in `setTimeout()` and other callbacks, instead of having to create a global reference to it:

```
with ({ copy }) { setTimeout(() => copy("copied!"), 0) }
```

`copied!` will now be on your clipboard. Unfortunately, this trick doesn't seem to work in Firefox's console.

Comment: Excellent answer! I used it inside a callback function that iterates over a the selected checkboxes and copies a list of their values to the clipboard.